# Deploying dotnet core to Heroku

Tags: asp.net, heroku, asp.net-core

I'm trying to deploy my dotnet core application to Heroku, but keep running up against this error:

```
Restore failed
unknown keyword platform
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Web app app.
 !     Push failed
```

When I use `dotnet run` from the CLI (I'm on a mac) everything runs fine. I've included my `Project.json` below in case that helps:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
  "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "type": "platform"
  },
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
  "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
  "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0",
  "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
  "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine": "1.0.0",
  "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
  "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
  "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
  "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
  "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite": "1.0.0",
  "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design": {
    "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "type": "build" 
  }
},

"tools": {
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-     final",
  "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
},

"frameworks": {
  "netcoreapp1.0": {
    "imports": [
      "dotnet5.6",
      "portable-net45+win8"
    ]
  }
},

"buildOptions": {
  "emitEntryPoint": true,
  "preserveCompilationContext": true
},

"runtimeOptions": {
  "configProperties": {
    "System.GC.Server": true
  }
},

"publishOptions": {
  "include": [
    "wwwroot",
    "Views",
    "Areas/**/Views",
    "appsettings.json",
    "web.config"
  ]
},

"tooling": {
  "defaultNamespace": "Tokens_monolith"
}
}
```

Comment: Do you have dotnet-cli and the .NET Core SDK/Runtime installed on Heroku?

Comment: I ran `heroku buildpacks:set https://github.com/jincod/dotnet-buildpack`  to set my buildpack and then deployed my code directly from github. It begins running `DNVM` before erroring out.

Comment: That's a vital information. The current ASP.NET Core don't use DNX anymore. Since RC2, (ASP).NET Core only runs on dotnet-cli. DNX is deprecated and won't be maintained or developed any further. DNVM is/was a DNX tool that would install the DNX runtime. .NET Core SDK/Runtime can be found here https://www.microsoft.com/net/core

Comment: The alternative is to run platform specific self-contained application, where you provide all necessary files with the deployment. Then .NET Core doesn't need to be installed, buy you have to provide all possible targets (linux, mac, windows, x86 or x64) in your project.json. For that read the .NET Core App Types MSDN page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/app-types

Comment: This is a huge help! Thanks you @Tseng for helping me out.

Comment: In case you find a concrete solution for your scenario post it as answer for other users who may cross over the same issue

Comment: Could anybody help me with the "Prockfile" for heroku, how does it look like ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I finally got this successfully deployed to Heroku, it's all up and running. Tseng was a huge help on this, so thank you. My buildpack that I was using was targeting an older version of .NET Core. Heroku has an experimental buildpack targeting ASPNET5 here: https://github.com/heroku/dotnet-buildpack.

As of the time of this answer, this buildpack is using Mono for runtime execution. There is a pull request to use the .NET CLI that I used and it works great. It can be found here: https://github.com/noliar/dotnet-buildpack. Hopefully they accept this pull request soon. This was the buildpack that I used.

Hope this helps someone.